# Python get certain coordinate from list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of coordinates,like :`[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6)]`

I want to get certain number, like `x1=1` from `(1,2,3)`, `y1=2` from `(1,2,3)`, I don't know if it can be done.

Because I want to calculate the distance between certain two coordinates.

use :

`math.sqrt(( x1-x2 )**2 + ( y1-y2 )**2 + (z1-z2 )**2)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexing to access items in a sequence. It is possible to use multiple indices to drill into a multidimensional array.

```
>>> seq = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6)]
>>> seq[0][0]
1
>>> seq[0][1]
2
```

Here, `seq[0][0]` accesses the first item in the first coordinate, and `seq[0][1]` accesses the second item in the first coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use a dictionary for that aim , you can get it whit list comprehension :

```
>>> [dict((('x%d'%index,x),('y%d'%index,y),('z%d'%index,z))) for index, (x, y, z) in enumerate(l,1)]
[{'y1': 2, 'x1': 1, 'z1': 3}, {'x2': 2, 'y2': 3, 'z2': 4}, {'x3': 3, 'y3': 4, 'z3': 5}, {'z4': 6, 'y4': 5, 'x4': 4}]
```

and then instead of `math.sqrt(( x1-x2 )**2 + ( y1-y2 )**2 + (z1-z2 )**2)` use :

```
math.sqrt((new_dic['x1']-new_dic['x2'] )**2 + ( new_dic['y1']-new_dic['y2'] )**2 + (new_dic['z1']-new_dic['z1'] )**2)
```

Comment: You can make the first snippet little beautiful by passing `1` as second argument to `enumerate` then you can simply use `index` and take the advantage of tuple unpacking: `for index, (x, y, z) in enumerate(l, 1)`